# shouldOverrideUrlLoading and onPageFinished are not working if both are on the code, but is working separately if I comment one of them

Tags: android, webview

This is the code part where I'm having the issues...

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.indexOf("tel:") > -1) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        view.loadUrl("javascript:replace('window.location.href', 'window.location')");
        view.loadUrl("javascript:replace('document.location.href', 'document.location')");
    }
});
```

I'm just adding on `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` the functionality to the `webview` to make calls when the link is a phone number, and adding some javascript code on `onPageFinished` to fix some issues that the `webview` has with `window.location.href` and `document.location.href`...

Thanks in advance for all the comments and replies, fixes and alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make new class which extends which extends WebViewClient.
Try this code snippet

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }

    }
```

Then used in your onCreate method.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

In this both function are calling.CheckOut this.

Answer (score 0):

Dhanyavaad!

My problem was in my `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. I was returning `true` when the link is NOT a phone number, now if the url is not a phone number, returns `super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);` and works perfectly.

Thanks Shashank your code open my eyes.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.indexOf("tel:") > -1) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
});
```